# How to write good docstrings for decorators in Python?

Tags: python, docstring

I have a problem with writing good and informative docstrings for decorators in Python. Let's say I have a following decorator:

```
def require_login(view):
    """
    Decorator for limiting access to a view for authenticated users only.

    :param view: view function to decorate
    :return: ???
    """
    @wraps(view)
    def wrapper(...):
        ...
    return wrapper
```

What should be described in `:return:`? "Decorated view"? It seems not very informative to for me, to be honest. What is the best way to describe a decorator without writing obvious things in documentation? And how to document a decorator with arguments such us:

```
def require_permission(permission_name):
    def decorator(view):
        @wraps(view)
        @require_login
        def wrapper(...):
            ...
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

If you know any good way to document decorators in Python, I would also appreciate all of your advices.

Comment: Is it really necessary to describe the return value of a decorator?

Comment: It is a good question. Do you suggest to simply omit the `return` part?

Comment: Yeah, doesn't seem like there's any point to it.